# setEGLconfigchooser changes color of object

Tags: android, opengl-es, transparent

I've created a GLsurfaceView which renders a square according to where i press the screen.
I want it to appear above a different layout.
in order to make it transparent i call:

```
    setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);
    mRenderer = new SlidingRenderer();
    setRenderer(mRenderer);
    getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

In my renderer:

```
 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){

     gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

but it also changes the color of my drawn square and makes it appear semi-transparent as well.

BEFORE:

[image: pic before]

AFTER:

[image: pic before]

Answer (score 0):

`TRANSLUCENT` is a vague pixel format descriptor, by its very definition the system is free to choose `RGBA_4444` or `RGBA_8888`.

Chances are very good that the system is configured to select the *minimal* pixel format that satisfies your conditions. For `PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT` those conditions are:

> System chooses a format that supports translucency (many alpha bits)

Since you probably want to match up with your EGL pixel format, try `PixelFormat.RGBA_8888` instead of `PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT`.

Comment: I changed it. It had no effect. i even commented out that line totaly and it still had no effect. I presume the problem is in setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,16,0);